# Why am I not seeing my platform driver in my Yocto distribution?

Tags: linux, driver, raspberry-pi3, yocto, device-tree

I am using Yocto for on a raspberry pi 3.
I patched my distribution's device tree so it contains the following simplistic node:

```
       mynode {
                compatible = "my_driver";
                firmware = <0x06>;
                status = "okay";
                phandle = <0x31>;
        };
```

This is the actual patch I applied:

```
+/ {
+       myNode: mynode {
+               compatible = "my_driver";
+               firmware = <0x06>;
+               status = "okay";
+               phandle = <0x31>;
+       };
+};
+
```

I also wrote a simplistic platform driver like so:

```
...
#include <linux/mod_devicetable.h>
#include <linux/of.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>

int my_probe(struct platform_device * pDev)
{
    printk("Entered my probe.\n");

    struct resource* regs = platform_get_resource(pDev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
    if (!regs) {
        dev_err(&pDev->dev, "could not get IO memory\n");
        printk("Failed to get resource\n");
        return -ENXIO;
    }

    printk("My module initialized.\n");

    return 0;
}

static int my_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    return 0;
}

static const struct of_device_id my_match_table[] = {
    {
        .compatible = "my_driver",
    },
    { },
};


static struct platform_driver my_platform_driver = {
    .probe      = my_probe,
    .remove     = my_remove,
    .driver     = {
        .name   = "my_driver",
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(my_match_table),
    },
};

static int __init my_init(void)
{
        printk("My driver's init\n");
        return platform_driver_probe(&my_platform_driver, my_probe);
}

static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
        printk("My driver's exit\n");
        platform_driver_unregister(&my_platform_driver);
}


module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, my_match_table);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

This is how I compile the driver itself:

```
obj-m += my_driver.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        rm -f *.ko *.symvers *.mod *.mod.c *.mod.o *.o *.order
```

I can see my node under:

- /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/mynode
- /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/symbols/myNode
- /sys/bus/platform/device/mynode
- sys/devices/platform/mynode

nothing on the system wrt "my_driver".

This is the recipe specifically for the driver:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"


LICENSE="CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM=""

ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"

SRC_URI = "file://src"
S = "${WORKDIR}/src"
TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}
```

So I set up a couple of things right so far. I do however:

- not see a my_driver entry in /dev
- not see my printk messages in dmesg when the system boots

I thought that with all of the above setup I should see something in my dmesg and under /dev. Yet, I don't see anything. Are there additional steps that need to be undertaken in order for this to happen? I thought that as my device tree's compatible property is the same as my platform's driver the kernel would match them and do what I just said above.

Is my understanding wrong? What am I missing here?

I tried going through the Linux's documentation again but nothing caught my attention. I at least expected something to appear in dmesg to understand what is going on, but nothing in there.

**EDIT:**

This is the device full tree https://pastebin.com/jvNnN0es

Comment: You need to proofread your post. You seem to claim that there are "*my printk messages in dmesg when the system boots*", and then contradict that with "*Yet, I don't see anything.*"  Your Device Tree node has no context. What is its parent node? Where did you install the module binary?

Comment: @sawdust yep went a bit too quickly. Fixed. Thanks

Comment: @sawdust I just added a link to my full device tree in the edit section. I put "mynode" at the root. I did not specify an installation directory... Where does it have to be installed in this case? Will try it out immediately...

Comment: @sawdust I did not specify an installation directory for my platform driver as I thought it would be compiled straight into the kernel somehow. Unlike device drivers which you "just" insmod/modprobe. Not sure what the most suited location would be here.

Comment: So you (unknowningly) built a *loadable* module using Yocto on a development machine? Where is this loadable module (named **my_driver.ko**) installed on your RPi for the kernel to use? "*I thought it would be compiled straight into the kernel somehow.*" -- Do you mean the module is supposed to be built-in, and part of the kernel image? That's not what your "*how I compile the driver itself*" is going to do. Inspect the **System.map** of your kernel for any trace of your code.

Comment: @sawdust I do indeed think this module is loadable. It is the kernel's job to load it at bootup based on the device tree's content. That's what I think... I don't know it it absolutely has to be built-in and part of the kernel. I am trying to learn and understand how this kind of drivers and dtrees work. As mentioned, I don't know where the has to be installed. Where does it have to be installed in that case for the kernel to be able to find it and match it with the device tree's content

Comment: Then check the Yocto build directory and the root filesystem of your RPi to see if you have that loadable module. Suggest you use the `find` command. Where in the kernel source does your code reside? Otherwise, I don't know which directory under /lib/modules/... it should be in.